# How to check for a dependency with autoconf?

Tags: autoconf

I have a program that is configured with a configure.ac file that crashes with some generic errors if libtool is not installed (unix).

How would I add a "check" for libtool that will provide a description, eg "libtool is not installed so the install failed" or something like that? I've never delved into this type of code before so have no idea

Thanks

Comment: This should only be an issue for the package maintainer. `libtool` is a script added to the package by running `libtoolize` or `autoreconf`.

Answer (score 0):

use PKG_CHECK_MODULES to ensure libtool is installed. 
Here is the documentation for the macro: https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html